# ssh remote access ubuntu

Tags: ssh

I need to find other computer specification such as ram speed and processor speed like that using ssh remote access in Ubuntu terminal through the same network! How can I do this? Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: So you just want to run commands like `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, `lshw`, `dmidecode -t memory` through ssh terminal, right? Or were you meaning something special?

Comment: yeah i need that one and also i share my files to do something then get back from the pc to my main pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know if this computer is running ssh. If so, type this:

```
rsh user@ip lshw
```

Comment: if it is running ssh then how can i get the details of that pc? is that possible to get details such as memory speed and processor speed ?

Comment: Yes, lshw gives you a summary of hardware you get at remote computer.

Comment: OK I'll try thank you so much for this big help :)

Comment: its worked thank you so much friend and one more help can i find this details in many pcs at the same time :(

Comment: Good! Rate my answer... To do it, you may have to make a script with a loop...

Comment: how can i do it as loop ? i'm new here so i do not much if you do not mind can you help me to solve this please :(

Comment: It's not so simple. Look this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers. Maybe it will work with `rsh`

Comment: okay i'll see it and thank you so much friend :)